# geoserver - adding externat value to use in ftl template

Tags: geoserver

how to add (to the layer?) value from url and use it as variable in ftl template?

I have image  mosaic layer and I would like to multiply value from each band by value from json accesible by specific url. I know it is impossible in ftl file but I wonder how can I put the variable to geoserver.

Many thanks

Comment: You may need to look at the WPS extension